# OBJ to Json to browser not working

Tags: javascript, three.js, .obj

I have converted my OBJ 3d Model into a .js file using this python script:

```
python convert_obj_three.py -i infile.obj -o outfile.js
```

but now I am having issues implementing the 3d model into my html. Im not sure what kind of script is necessary to load the .js file or .obj if that works. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check that the version of the converter script is compatible with the json format version used by the three.js release you're using.

Regardless, you can probably simply load the .obj file directly in three.js: check out the [loader obj example](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_loader_obj)

[image: loader obj example]

Another quick'n'dirty option, if you really must convert the .obj to a .json file is simply to:

1. load the [three.js editor](https://threejs.org/editor/) in a tab
2. drag your .obj file into it (and scale/transform as needed)
3. export a .json file via **File > Export Object** or simply grab the whole three.js project from the editor via **File > Publish**

Comment: I've tried to  use the obj loader as which you provided me with. However, I can't seem to import my own obj files. Any clues?

Comment: Are getting any errors ? if so please share. Can you also share the model ?

Comment: woo hoo! nice one @Topish :)

Comment: in general, check:
 - if the model is loaded (path to file is correct and .obj file can be parsed)
 - if the geometry is present (vertices/faces are there and succesfully parsed)
 - if the scale isn't too big or too small so it can't be seen in the viewport
 - if the normals are facing the right way (but a double sided wireframe material should help debug)

Answer (score 0):

I use https://clara.io/ tool to export to Json. Then in the html use https://threejs.org/ lib to load and render the model.